# Replace nth matching line with sed

Tags: sed

I have a script that output about 50 lines and there are about five lines that match when I am trying to replace only one of them.

Example:

```
...
metadata
 name: A
...
spec:
- labels:
...
    name: B
  name: C
- labels:
...
    name: D
  name: E
```

I am trying to use sed to replace the entire of "name: B" to "name: {firstVar}" and "name: D" to "name: {secondVar}". I know that I can just search for the whole line "name: B" or "name: D" but these aren't always going to be the same and can be changed by others. The only thing that's consistent is their placement. So, I am looking to be able to replace the 2nd and 4th match but anytime I try "s/name:.*/name: {firstVar}/2" or something similar it doesn't work or it will replace all the matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like YAML. Have you tried using a YAML parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
second="firstVar" fourth="secondVar"
sed -z 's/\(name:\s*\)[^\n]*/\1'"$second"'/2;s//\1'"$fourth"'/4' file
```

Set variables in the shell and then use them as replacements in the pattern matching substitutions. The positive integer flag  in the substitution command replaces that number pattern in the pattern space. The `-z` option, slurps the whole of the the file into memory and thus the pattern space contains the whole of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    a[2]="firstVar"                                  # define the pairs
    a[4]="secondVar"
} 
$1=="name:" {                                        # search for match
    sub($1 " " $2,$1 " " ((++i in a)?a[i]:$2),$0)    # replace
}1' file
```

Output:

```
...
metadata
 name: A
...
spec:
- labels:
...
    name: firstVar
  name: C
- labels:
...
    name: secondVar
  name: E
```

Comment: Whoops, I used A and B instead of C and D but fixing it is left as an excersize.

Comment: Didn't think about awk. I was so hung up on sed. I'll give that a go and see how it works with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So, looking at this, you're replacing just if anything matches with "A" or "B". Unfortunately, for something that I'm doing, it won't always be A or B. Those names are completely dynamic. Which is why I was looking to replace the 2nd and 4th match of the key "name: " rather than just that value. Thanks though. Going to look more into awk as well

Comment: Updated the solution.